# Bind more than one ViewModel in View in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone

I have a ViewModel class "MyViewModel" and inside I have an ObservableCollection "MyCollection".

Then in the view code-behind I do this to set the data context:

```
this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

and in the front-end of the view

```
<Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1">
```

But what if I need to use different ViewModel "MyViewModel2" with "MyCollection2" inside in this View. How can I skip this step:

```
this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

and bind only in xaml?

I tried this but without any result:

```
<Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModel.MyCollection}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1">
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to bind several different view model to different user controls on your view?

Comment: Im trying to achieve exactly this!

Comment: Each user control that has its own data context - that shouldn't be an issue. The view can has a different data context too. What is the issue that you are having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better to use two collections in the same view model...
Or you can use a master ViewModel class with reference to two sub-viewmodels; something like this:

**MyViewModel class:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> DataInfo { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        DataInfo = new ObservableCollection<string>();            
    }
}
```

**MasterViewModel class:**

```
public class MasterViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel VM1 { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel VM2 { get; set; }

    public MasterViewModel()
    {
        this.VM1 = new MyViewModel();
        this.VM2 = new MyViewModel();

        VM1.DataInfo.Add("Data 1-1");
        VM1.DataInfo.Add("Data 1-2");

        VM2.DataInfo.Add("Data 2-1");
        VM2.DataInfo.Add("Data 2-2");
    }
}
```

**View code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MasterViewModel();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="DeleteMe4SOw.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding VM1.DataInfo}" Height="150" Margin="10" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding VM2.DataInfo}" Height="150" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my master class:

```
class CompositeViewModel
{
    public TripsResponseTypeViewModel tripsResponseTypeViewModel { get; set; }
    public TripsViewModel tripsViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

in TripsResponseTypeViewModel I have:

```
...
    private ObservableCollection<TripsResponseType> _tripsViewModelDataSource;
    public ObservableCollection<TripsResponseType> TripsViewModelDataSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == this._tripsViewModelDataSource)
            {
                this._tripsViewModelDataSource = new ObservableCollection<TripsResponseType>();
            }

            return this._tripsViewModelDataSource;
        }
    }
...
```

In my View I want to set this TripsViewModelDataSource to ItemsSource of a Pivot like this:

```
<Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding tripsResponseTypeViewModel.TripsViewModelDataSource}"...
```

In View.xaml.cs I did as you said:

```
this.DataContext = new CompositeViewModel();
```

and nothing..

Comment: Updated my reply with an exactly copy paste from a working sample